# reqular expression is giving None always

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

This is my code

```
>>> ll = 'window.DETAILS_PAGE_MAP_GLOBALS = {GOOGLE_MAPS_LONGITUDE: 55.2378015294,GOOGLE_MAPS_LATITUDE: 25.0463764816}'
>>> print(re.match('GOOGLE_MAPS_LATITUDE:\s*(\d+\.\d+)', ll))
None
```

I always get `None` **though I am sure 100% that the regular expression is correct.**

could you help please?

Comment: It is not duplicated guys. I didn't know that I have to use search instead of match. please be more careful about these things. consider that not all users are professionals in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `re.search()` instead of `re.match()`. The first one is looking to the pattern anywhere in the string, and the other one looks if the pattern can be applied to the string **exactly**.

[From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search):

> `re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)`
>
> **Scan through string looking for** a location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding match object. Return `None` **if no position in the string matches the pattern**; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

Example:

```
>>> print(re.search('GOOGLE_MAPS_LATITUDE:\s*(\d+\.\d+)', ll))
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xffecf260>
>>> print(re.search('GOOGLE_MAPS_LATITUDE:\s*(\d+\.\d+)', ll).groups())
('25.0463764816',)
>>> print(re.search('GOOGLE_MAPS_LATITUDE:\s*(\d+\.\d+)', ll).group(1))
25.0463764816
```

Comment: what is this comma? and can I get the value without the `(` and the `)` please?

Comment: Yes, you can. See my answer updated. Make sure to check if the `re.search()` object returned is not `None` before trying to call `group()` method.

Comment: Many thanks, will accept it once the system allows +1

Comment: For the record, the second line returns a tuple: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Comment: is this question really a duplicated one? I didn't know that `search` could help.

Comment: It is kind of a duplicate but it is hard to say for me it is one, since you didn't know the existence of the function (even though, a quick look in the documentation would have solved your problem). I would not have flag it as duplicate with this question.

Comment: I already looked at the documentation and really tried the `search` but I got a strange results ( I am sure you know that results). So, I didn't think that search is good in my case

Answer (score 1):

Use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search), *not* `re.match()`; the latter only matches *at the start of the string*:

> If zero or more characters **at the beginning of *string*** match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding `MatchObject` instance.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> ll = 'window.DETAILS_PAGE_MAP_GLOBALS = {GOOGLE_MAPS_LONGITUDE: 55.2378015294,GOOGLE_MAPS_LATITUDE: 25.0463764816}'
>>> re.match('GOOGLE_MAPS_LATITUDE:\s*(\d+\.\d+)', ll)
>>> re.search('GOOGLE_MAPS_LATITUDE:\s*(\d+\.\d+)', ll)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x105525cd8>
>>> re.search('GOOGLE_MAPS_LATITUDE:\s*(\d+\.\d+)', ll).group(1)
'25.0463764816'
```

Comment: I already tried the `search` syntax and I've got the exact same result u got. but how to see the actual number ? I am searching for `latitude` value

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: you mean you want the group? The returned `MatchObject` has a `.group()` method, and you already are using `(..)` to capture the value into group 1, so use `.group(1)` to extract it.

Comment: Many thanks for the efforts +1,

Comment: is this really a duplicated question? I didn't know that `search` is beneficial in my case

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: well, it does appear that the difference between `re.search()` and `re.match()` is what threw you off.